# JSON_EXTRACT path generated from JSON_SEARCH with 'all ' mode is NOT working

Tags: mysql

How can I use JSON_EXTRACT `path` argument, that is generated from JSON_SEARCH with **`all`** search mode? 
 *Mode `one` is working properly*.

```
set @data = '[{"answer":"1","id":4,"isValid":true},{"answer":"1","id":189,"isValid":true},{"answer":"1","id":356,"isValid":true},{"answer":"0","id":420,"isValid":false},{"answer":"0","id":504,"isValid":true},{"answer":"1","id":531,"isValid":true},{"answer":"0","id":583,"isValid":true},{"answer":"0","id":625,"isValid":true},{"answer":"1","id":742,"isValid":true},{"answer":"1","id":951,"isValid":true},{"answer":"0","id":1012,"isValid":false},{"answer":"1","id":1057,"isValid":true},{"answer":"1","id":1100,"isValid":true},{"answer":"1","id":1170,"isValid":true},{"answer":"0","id":1200,"isValid":true},{"answer":"1","id":1233,"isValid":true},{"answer":"0","id":1329,"isValid":false},{"answer":"0","id":1471,"isValid":true}]';  

SELECT
    @path_to_name := json_unquote(json_search(@data, 'all', FALSE)) AS path_to_name,
    @path_to_parent := TRIM( TRAILING ']' FROM TRIM( LEADING '[' FROM REPLACE (@path_to_name, '.answer', '.id'))) AS path_to_parent,
    json_extract(@data, @path_to_parent) AS notValid
```

I want to get values **`420,1012,1329`**.

Comment: Parse recieved array to separate paths then apply JSON_EXTRACT.

Comment: That's a bit too broad. Please show us sample data, desired results, and your current query (or queries).

Comment: @GMB I added the query on post.

Comment: When you use the `'all'` search mode, it returns a JSON array of paths, not a single path. So you get `path_to_parent: "$[3].id", "$[4].id", "$[6].id", "$[7].id", "$[10].id", "$[14].id", "$[16].id", "$[17].id"`. What were you expecting this to do as an argument to `JSON_EXTRACT()`? It's not a valid JSON path.

Comment: Yes, I know and that's why I tried to remove  the square brackets. Since  ```json_extract()```  can have more than one path, I added it dynamically, but it still shows a not valid json path error message. Is there any solution for retrieving the result I want?